# How can I find the JavaScript that is setting the inline style of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering of there is any way to find out where an inline CSS style came from. As you can see in the picture below, I have an element with an inline style that was generated using JavaScript. Sometimes my code seems to break and put the width to 0px, rendering the div invisible.

[image: screenshot]

I've looked through all the JS files, but can't seem to find the error.

Is there a way to find the right file and line, just like dev tools does for css files?

Comment: If you include your code and any libraries you are using, one of us may be able to find the culprit. But to answer your question, I don't know of any mechanism that will clearly tell you the source of an applied style.

Comment: don't know about grep, might work. I'll have a look at it, but it seems quite complicated.

Comment: Grep is very simple, it is just a command line tool that allows you to search files for strings. It isn't very helpful unless you know a string that occurs near the code you care about but not in many other places in your codebase.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are using Chrome:

1. Right click on the element in the page and *Inspect Element*
2. Right click on the DOM inspector view of the element and *Break on… → Attributes Modifications*

When the inline style of the element is modified with JS, the debugger will trigger as if it had hit a breakpoint.

This will show you the relevant line of JS and give you a stack so you can figure out where that line was called from.

Comment: ok, it's abit of a workaround but it might work. thanks, will give it a shot.

Comment: If you're new to debugger, it might take you a while (it did for me) to realise that you need to press F5 (not Ctrl+R) to refresh the page and see the breakpoint in action.

Comment: Note that sometimes its hard to place the breakpoint at the right time, because the html breakpoint can get lost on dynamically generated elements. In the html, add a `<script>debugger;</script> right after the element you are wanting to inspect. This allows for a simple way to pause the code early on, allowing you to Inspect and add the breakpoint in. More context at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331222/339803

Answer (score -1):

You can use chrome debugger/ firefox to inspect the element's style and its hierarchy.

Also if you don't want a style assigned by you to be overridden, you can use !important:

```
#element{

css-property:value !important;
}
```

Comment: The OP already knows that it is set directly on the element. They are trying to track down the JS that set it there.

Comment: yes, I know that. But that still doesn't tell me which Javascript file generated a specific bit of inline CSS.

Comment: important should be avoided most of the times. Only use it for status modifiers such as a warning that wants to override text or background colors with a color: red !important for example.